# jQuery Isotope not applying layout. Inheritance the issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, wordpress

I'm having trouble getting the loop to align in the classic Masonry style layout with the jquery Isotope module.

All browsers are loading the script fine in console, but the attributes don't see to be working at all. The alignment for the .item class div elements are all right up the left side and stacked horizontally.

Does Wordpress have some kind of inheritance blocking it from working? I'm trying this on the default TwentyTwelve theme for wordpress with no other plugins, but it is in a positin:fixed; div wrapping it to the lower 50% of the page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>js/jquery.isotope.js">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#container').isotope({
            $container.isotope({
                itemSelector:'.item'
            });
      masonry: {
        columnWidth: 20
      };

    });
            </script>
```

Followed by the calls to html:

```
                 <div id="container" >
                    <div class="item">
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');
                            }?>

                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

With these applicable CSS attributes, which I'm thinking shouldn't be the problem...

```
    #container {
        position:relative;
    }
    .item {
        width:50px;
        height:auto;
        border:1px;
    }
```

A live example for where it is now is here: justingaskin.com

Comment: Where is ` $container` defined?, also I've never used `isotope` before, but it appears like you're calling it twice.

Comment: Could be. I'm still coming to grips with back end developing js. Would a live example help?

Comment: A live example would help.

Comment: After looking at the `isotope` documentation, you definitely have it set-up wrong. Check out my answer below.

Comment: Added the URL to the live sample. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: I edited my previous answer. You need to make sure all the include files are added properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're calling `isotope` twice, it should look like this

> $( '#container' ).isotope({
>
> itemSelector   : '.item',
>         masonry       : {
>       columnWidth: 20   }
>
> });

**EDIT**

After taking a look at your Wordpress site, you're no loading the `isotope` jQuery file properly. Right now, if you check out the console, you'll notice that the request to `jquery.isotope.js` failed. The location of the `isotope` file should be:

`http://justingaskin.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-masonry/js/jquery.isotope.js`

and on your site its:

`http://justingaskin.com/js/jquery.isotope.js`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>js/jquery.isotope.js">`  <-- This is **wrong**

It should be:

`script type="text/javascript" src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]; ?>/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve-masonry/js/jquery.isotope.js">`

Comment: Thanks! I thought I got all the little nuances when taking localhost test sites and going live with them. I've since popped in my temporary content, but the masonry still isn't operating the way it should be like the manual says it should be. This is where my question about inheritance being the issue sets in... I've seen some mention of needing a position:relative for the item, but after trying that and not seeing any results I'm skeptical of any other issues I might be missing.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was definitely an inheritance issue. When reformatting the TwentyTwelve theme that comes with Wordpress (currently as of date of posting), there are a slew factors that flow (cascade... hernt) to the items that I was trying to organize.

Using the tutorial and guidance from this link: http://www.wplover.com/1818/tutorial-using-jquery-masonry-with-wordpress/

I was able to wipe the loop-slate clean and scrub in a fresh coat of css to the elements I needed control of in the first place.

Thanks for the help @c-misura !